Which Nuxt hook to use for loading third-party javascript
What is the right Nuxt hook to use if I want to run something after the page has fully loaded and all suspense operations / dependency fetching is done?
My goal is to load third-party javascript after all the things that affect rendering the page for the user.
When I use the normal window load event it happens before most of the Nuxt hooks, which makes me think I should be using a later Nuxt hook instead.


As you can see, from the log, page:loading:end could be what you need, and also app:suspense:resolve. Generally speaking it would be https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/suspense#events in root component. Notice that there could be nested suspense and no specific point where an app is considered fully rendered, this is general problem with SPA apps

@EstusFlask - Thanks. For what it is worth I did try page:loading:end after posting this and it is called on every page transition. Currently using app:mounted, but this may not be ideal?

Yes, mounted doesn't take suspended comps into account at least
